# Angular html form - dropdown not populating value in MySql Database

Tags: angular

Might be a simple question but my currencies in my Html form were populating on the database when they were in the Html form entered as

Now that I use select to display dropdown they do not

html change from:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="billing.currency" name="currency" id="currency" placeholder="Add currency">
```

to

```
<select>
    <option value=0>--Select a Currency--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let dropdown of listDropdown" [value]="dropdown.Currency">{{dropdown.Currency}}</option>
  </select>
```

Typescript Model

```
export interface Billing {
id?: number,
ccode?: number,
customer?: number,
date?: Date,
amount?: number,
currency?: string,
text?: string,
favourite?: boolean,
```

};

How to fix that?
Thanks

Comment: select dropdowns are a bit more complex. I'm not exactly sure how they work with ngModel, but keep in mind you have to populate the list of items, also choose one of the items to be "selected" and then have a method that handles when you change a selection. Might need to look up how they are used.

Comment: maybe post your select html too. and by the way, I'm not sure how you go from a number input, which has an infinite number of possibilities, to a select type. Doesn't seem like a good change.

Comment: I do see the dropdowns . It is more that I cannot get the dropdown values selected to populate in my database. For instance if I select currency USD - the database shows it blank. It is like it does not recognise the format. And sorry type currency is text in my html and typescript model. Before changing to dropdown USD was getting populated

Comment: Would you mind sharing your component ts and service ts please?

Comment: I don't think it's likely the problem is with your db. Add a console.log() of the FormGroup before actually making any requests... the value will likely be null in your form. You need to properly bind the UI to the form value. The fact you can see a dropdown and can select a value does not mean the value is in your FormGroup. Like Rick said, just check an example of a select in a template form.

Answer (score 0):

doing a quick google search I found this. You probably need your set up in a similar way:

```
<select . . . name="duration" [(ngModel)]="exercisePlan.duration"> 
  <option *ngFor="let duration of durations" [value]="duration.value">. {{duration.title}}</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be consistend with the type of your value, string or number.
Also, bind the value of the select and then assign values to the options:

```html
<select name="currency" [(ngModel)]="currency">
    <option selected value="0">--Select a Currency--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let dropdown of listDropdown" value="dropdown.Currency">{{dropdown.Currency}}</option>
</select>
```

You can then do a check for the string '0' upon submit (as a condition to make the request, or as validation) if you don't want to send the default value of '0' to your db.

Comment: If you can't get it to work, make a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) so we can more easily help you with your code. I will gladly take a look if you do.

Comment: Thanks - the type is text for currency. so should I replace the zero with "text"? When I click submit button it runs a method that runs the [request.body]  as per below:
const billing = await dbDATA.query('INSERT INTO MB2021.DATABASE SET ?', [req.body]);  
    resp.json(billing);
I presume I need somehow to connect this to the dropdown value currency ?

Comment: Whatever object you are creating from your form data () should be passed into the request body, yes. You don't need to pass a type to the selector. You are providing the only possible options in the listDropdown array. ('Unless you want the selector to be writable for ¿custom? currencies? But that wouldn't make much sense in this case. XD The 0 is only so you have a unique value to do a 'check' on in code, for validation for example... It could be any unique value.